# align pieces of a split line in html

Tags: html, css

I want to show some text in a, say, < h6 > element. The content is mostly fixed but few lines with some variable content I know may be too long.

- I prefer to use \n to organize the source text in lines as I want, because this way is very convenient in the source file;
- I want the pieces of split text to be shown centered or right aligned, I will have to decide;
- I want to indicate myself the optional splitting points, with < wbr > or something as I know the problematic lines and how I want to split them when they exceed length;
- The first part of the split line I want to remain left aligned.

For example, in case of right aligned split:

```
Information foo: This is a normal line of text
Information bla:
             This is a line which had to be split
```

In case of center aligned split:

```
Information foo: This is a normal line of text
Information bla:
       This is a line which is very long and
             definitely would not fit
```

I found no solution to meet all these criteria. One annoying result was as such:

```
Information foo: This is a short line of text
Information bla:
Information  This is a line which is very long
bar: The line uses the space not occupied above
```

This happens, for example, with "float:right". I think is not possible to apply some style only to the element containing text but I prefer not to have each line in an element. As I said, using \n to organize the content is very content. If possible, I would limit the usage of additional elements only to too long parts, like this:

```
<pre>
    Information foo: This is a normal line of text\n
    Information bla:
         <span>This is a content which had to be split<span>\n
</pre>
```

Another attempt would be like

```
<elem style="white-space: pre-wrap">
    Information foo: This is a normal line of text\n
    Information bla:
         </elem><elem>This is a content which had to be split</elem><elem>\n
    Details: some other line
</elem>
```

but not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: CSS can't style words, it can only style elements; so if you want to align words to opposite ends of a parent element, those words would have to be in an element.

Comment: Unless you are using `<pre>` _everywhere_ (please don't), `\n` isn't a good approach for line breaks in HTML.

Comment: @DBS Well, I am willing to use, say, <br/> instead of \n. Or anything else which is simple enough.

Comment: I don't understand the issue; maybe consider making the question more understandable. Also, can you give us an example of your source text you are trying to split.

Comment: I understand that you have a text line starting from left. In the middle, you have \n, which breaks the line. Everything after the \n should be aligned to the right in the new line?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
<p style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    Temporibus quisquam harum fugit et id: \n dolore ducimus quia, nisi ab?
</p>
```

Then, use JS to separate and process the text.

```
const p = document.querySelector("p");
const text = p.textContent;
const splitText = text.split("\\n");
splitText[1] = `<span style="align-self: flex-end;">${splitText[1]}</span>`;
p.innerHTML = splitText.join("<br>");
```

If you don't want it to be on the absolute right, you can replace the `align-self: flex-end;` with `padding-left`.

**Keep in mind: `<br>` elements will be removed from the text!**

```
<p> blabla <br> blabla <p> will be <p>blablablablabla</p>
unless \n is in the middle.
```

Anyway, what you are trying to do is a bit unusual so that you will have unusual answers :)

Answer (score 0):

In the example below shows simple use of CSS class selectors and HTML inline-block elements. Details are in the text of the HTML.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

h5 {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}

main {
  margin: 10vh 5vw 10vh 2.5vw;
  resize: both;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

section+section {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

section:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

code,
var {
  font-family: Consolas;
  color: navy;
}

var {
  color: grey;
}

.NwSe {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.5;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(2);
}


/**
 * The following rulesets are discussed within the text of the HTML.
 */

.seg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.hdr {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.txt {
  width: 80%;
}

.c {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(140, 191, 242, 0.3);
}

.r {
  text-align: right;
  background: rgba(255, 139, 39, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h5>Resize <code>&lt;main&gt;</code></h5>
    <p>Scroll to the bottom then click and drag the right side corner. <b class="NwSe">⬄</b></p>
  </header>
  <hr>
  <section>
    <h6 class="seg hdr">First segment is left aligned: </h6>
    <span class="seg txt r">Second segment is right aligned.</span>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h6 class="seg hdr">First segment is left aligned: </h6>
    <span class="seg txt c">Second segment is center aligned.</span>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h6 class="seg hdr">HTML: </h6>
    <span class="seg txt c">Wrap a <code>&lt;h6&gt;</code> for each header text (first segment) and the remaining text in a <code>&lt;span&gt;</code>. Wrap the <code>&lt;h6&gt;</code> and <code>&lt;span&gt;</code>s in a <code>&lt;section&gt;</code>. Assign classes that have specific styles.</span>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h6 class="seg hdr">CSS: </h6>
    <span class="seg txt r">Each segment (<code>h6.seg</code> and <code>span.seg</code>) has the style <code>display: inline-block</code> so they'll sit next to each other and <code>vertical-align: top</code> so that the text always starts at the top. <code>&lt;h6&gt;</code> has <code>width: fit-content</code> so that it only is as wide as it's unbroken text. Each <code>span.seg</code> within is <var>80%</var> of the <code>&lt;section&gt;</code>'s width.</span>
  </section>
  <hr>
</main>
```

Comment: The thing is that in case we don't have split, the second segment is still right or center aligned. I want to stay left aligned to look like the rest of the text unless is split. And I want the split to be triggered not by some percentage but depending on whether it fist or not one line.

Comment: Sorry, it looks as if your examples don't fully explain what you actually want to do and your explanation is confusing (I speak only for myself, maybe there are other people that grok).  Specific behavior that is far from standard can be done with JavaScript. I suggest you research, experiment, and when you have a problem that you can't resolve (you probably will, we all do at one time or another), comeback and post the code as a [mcve] and add the [tag:javascript] tag to it as well.